# Dynamic labels no longer update in Orbeon Xforms when oxf.xforms.cache.document is set to false

Tags: orbeon

Why is it that when I set the 'oxf.xforms.cache.document' property to false in my local properties file, dynamic labels for buttons and fieldsets no longer seem to update correctly.

I am using the following xform to test this:

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:fr="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/form-runner"
xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
xmlns:xxf="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms">
<xhtml:head>
    <xhtml:title>Dynamic label</xhtml:title>
    <xf:model id="m-default">
        <xf:instance id="i-default">
            <default xmlns="">
                <in />
            </default>
        </xf:instance>
        <xxf:var name="input" value="instance('i-default')/in" />
    </xf:model>
</xhtml:head>
<xhtml:body>
    <xhtml:h1>Dynamic label</xhtml:h1>
    <xf:group ref="instance('i-default')" appearance="xxf:fieldset">
        <xf:label>
            <xf:output value="count(instance('i-default')[in != ''])" />
        </xf:label>
        <xf:input ref="$input" incremental="true">
            <xf:label>
                <xf:output value="'Input: '" />
            </xf:label>
        </xf:input>
        <xhtml:div>
            <xf:group ref=".[$input != '']">
                <xf:trigger>
                    <xf:label>
                        <xf:output value="$input" />
                    </xf:label>
                </xf:trigger>
            </xf:group>
        </xhtml:div>
    </xf:group>
</xhtml:body>
```

When the property is set to true and I type something in the input field, the label of the fieldset will update to 1 and the button will appear with a label containing the same text as the input field. When the property is set to false the button will appear when I type something the first time, but the fieldset label will not update to 1 and any subsequent entries will not change the label on the button anymore.

Tested this with Orbeon 4.6.0.201406210117-CE.

Answer (score 0):

For reference this is a bug and we have entered an issue [here](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1880).